# longitude lattitude performance

Tags: mysql, performance

I have to store frequently (at least every min) the position (longitude, latitude) of animals in a DB, and perform for each update a search in order to determinate if ananother animal is near to it.

My question is about performance. I plan to use MySQL and FLOAT (10,6) for these variables.

- Does a better SQL type exist for this kind of problem in MySQL?  It seems Microsoft released their GEOGRAPHY TYPE, maybe something exists in other DB manager?
- Is it a good idea to create an index on these values (because I update them a lot but also search on them a lot)? If yes, what kind of index is the best (CLUSTERED)?
- Do you have any advice for querying the DB?

Thanks.

Comment: I answered a similar question recently: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71509/efficiently-searching-geolocations-lat-lng-and-decimals/71543#71543 MySQL supports spatial data types like POINT and R-Trees (spatial indexes), although older MySQL versions have some important features missing: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/gis-data-formats.html